# How to Loop through XML and invoke a procedure Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, cursor

I have XML doc in this format

```
<parent_node>
 <categoryID>1</categoryID>
 <categoryID>2</categoryID>
 <categoryID>3</categoryID>
</parent_node>
```

I am passing this XML to a procedure now for each categoryID in XML document I have to call a stored procedure for each categoryID in XML document which will do its work and return me a integer value then I should Update a column of a table called of category master with the returned integer value for the respective category. How to Go About it . Should I open a cursor for the XML docu I dont know How to open a cursor for XML document also its good if we can avoid cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by putting the Xml content in a temp table and then open a cursor on the temptable